# google places autocomplete API limit to only universities

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

Hello I am having an issue with the Google places Autocomplete API. I am looking to have it so users can only search for universities. Is this possible? This is my current code:

```
    //Limits search results to only us places.
    var options = {
    types: ['university','establishment'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
    };

  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);    
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='0')
    {  ?>
    $('.advanced_search').show();
      <?php } elseif($this->uri->segment(2)=='edit') { ?>
   $('.advanced_search_rooms').hide();   
   <?php }
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently this is not possible on the client side (with the JS API v3). The available Autocomplete instantiation otpions are available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions).

You can instanciate your Autocomplete so results are restricted within a country with the **componentRestriction** option. You can also restrict results to a certain type of places with the **types** option, but the only choices are 'geocode', 'establishment', '(regions)', '(cities)'.
Schools and universities are of 'establishment' type, so you will get them if you use this, but they'll be retrieved along with any business establishment.

The code would look like the following.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='js-autocomplete' />
```

JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById('js-autocomplete');
var autocompleteSchools = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, {
    types: ['establishment']
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nemile/4fem2x7r/